# Breaker trips when turning switch on with no load (No GFCI)

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

This circuit is a dedicated light circuit with 7 can lights. I removed all the bulbs, turned the switch on, breaker trips. I swapped the switch, breaker trips. I' guessing there's a short circuit somewhere but how to go about locating it? The can light wiring is in the attic near the eaves, not easy to access. Is there a way to test the can lights from below or just suck it up and low crawl to each fixture? Once I'm there, how to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't test the wiring periodically as you installed it, it is now for you to do.

I would sever off lamps 4-7 at the lamp 3 junction, relight, see if the problem clears.  Then divide the remaining area-of-uncertainty in half and repeat, in half again repeat.  Now you are down to 1 light, it is that light or the one before.

If it helps, get some 3/4" plywood and lay it across the joists so you have a roadway and don't put your foot through the ceiling.

Comment: I've been all over the attic and have a little super highway built to get around. Lights branch off 2 on way and 5 another. For the record, I didn't install these, just inherited the issue. Thank you for your answer, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Got it sorted and found the non working unit. Thank you for the logic diagram.